# Google slides API - setting a table's columnWidth

Tags: javascript, google-slides-api, google-slides

Im trying to produce a table that looks similar to a different table i get from another presentation, but the width of the table columns is incorrect.

I noticed that there is no batch update request for changing the table column properties. is there any other way I can use to set the columnWidth property of my tables properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now set a table column's width via [UpdateTableColumnPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetablecolumnpropertiesrequest).